# Does this code I wrote do what we expect from the quick sort algorithm?

Tags: java, beginner, algorithm, quick-sort

```
package labodeva;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class odev5dene {
static int[] quick(int kucuk,int buyuk,int[] arr,int pivot) {
    int bos[] = new int[100];
    int t=0;
    while(kucuk<=buyuk) { // buyuk is big kucuk is small
        if(arr[kucuk]<=arr[pivot]) {
        kucuk++;
        }
        else if(arr[buyuk]>arr[pivot]) {
        buyuk--;
        }
        else{
            bos[0] = arr[kucuk];
            arr[kucuk]=arr[buyuk];
            arr[buyuk] = bos[0];
            buyuk--;
            kucuk++;
        }
    }
     if(kucuk>buyuk) {
             bos[0] = arr[pivot];
                arr[pivot]=arr[buyuk];
                arr[buyuk]=bos[0];
                 pivot=buyuk; //sil
         }
     if(pivot-1>0&&pivot+1<arr.length) {
         quick(0,pivot-1,arr,0);
         quick(pivot+1,arr.length-1,arr,pivot+1);
         }
      if(pivot+1<arr.length&&pivot-1<0) {
          quick(pivot+1,arr.length-1,arr,pivot+1);
     }
     return arr;
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a =0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter how many value do you want to add the array : ");
        a=scan.nextInt();
        int k[] =new int[a]; 
        for(int i=0;i<a;i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter your "+(i+1)+".value");
            k[i]=scan.nextInt();
        }
        k=quick(0,a-1,k,0); // it starts 0. element as pivot and goes on and also small and equal number value starts here big number value starts at the end of list
        for(int i=0;i<a;i++) {
            System.out.println(k[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

i wrote this code and it sorts the given array but i tried to do quicksort is this quicksort i am not sure can you check ?

Comment: (I always found it slightly more taxing to follow source code with comments&identifiers in my first language, and keywords in English as compared to sticking to (Pidgin) English.)

Comment: I expect a *production strength* quicksort implementation to a) use additional space growing not nearly as fast as the number *n* of items *even worst case* b) not show worst case time for reverse sorted input, let alone sorted one.

Answer (score 2):

1. In quicksort, when you are sorting from elements 20 to 40, and the split becomes 30, the recursive calls should be to sort 20 to 29 and 31 to 40.  You did 0 to 29 and 31 to max.  I suspect this made your code degenerate into an \$O(n^2)\$ sort (but still work).
2. In quicksort, you should not pass in a pivot.  The function should work that out itself.
3. Variable bos is a problem.  You only ever use bos[0], so you shouldn't even make an array, just a simple variable.